# Maven Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3

Tags: java, maven-3, exec-maven-plugin

hi im using maven to compile a jersey web services project and im getting error compiling it in windows 2008 server.

Here is the error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MyApplication>mvn -e exec:java
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBu
ilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyApplication 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java (default-cli) @ MyApplication ---
[WARNING] Warning: killAfter is now deprecated. Do you need it ? Please comment on MEXEC-6.
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rb.resource.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.244 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-31T12:20:54+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/91M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java (default-cli) on project
 MyApplication: An exception occured while executing the Java class. rb.resource.Main -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exe
c-maven-plugin:1.3:java (default-cli) on project MyApplication: An exception occured while executi
ng the Java class. rb.resource.Main
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBu
ilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBu
ilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(Si
ngleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the
Java class. rb.resource.Main
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.j
ava:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rb.resource.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following arti
cles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MyApplication>
```

Here is my maven and java version:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-15T01:37:52+08:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: c:\Progra~1\Java\jre8
Default locale: en_SG, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows server 2008 r2", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Here is the content for my pom.xml in Windows 2008. The pom.xml content is slightly different mac. (e.g: java version, :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApplication</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyApplication</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support:
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.4</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Log4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.company.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.company.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.7</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Are there any special options necessary to execute it using Java 8? Can you get any Java 8 project to compile? Is that version of Jersey compatible with Java 8? Just asking because I had a boat load of issues getting Maven to "do the right thing" with Java 8 last week.

Comment: hi, i reverted to java 7 and update pom.xml but still facing the same problem.

Comment: Well, the obvious error is ```java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rb.resource.Main```. The cause is bad configuration of the exec plugin, most likely your configuration of the main class. Is ```rb.resource.Main``` your class? Is ```org.company.Main``` a stub you forgot to configure?

Comment: hello, tks for that. i corrected it. sigh but still having the same error

Comment: Well, the last place to look is your directory structure. Make sure that ```rb.resource.Main``` is indeed a Java class located at ```{project.root}/src/main/java/rb/resource/Main.java```, and that this ```pom.xml``` is at the ```{project.root}```.

Comment: hi, yes i have verified the java file and pom file location. i could run this without problem on mac os x.

Comment: i copied the same code from mac os x to windows 2008 and windows 7. it didn't work on both windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try compile the project first. Run your command as before but slightly modified:

```
mvn -e compile exec:java
```

Justification:
Of course I don't have your sources and cannot be 100% sure but I have the very same error if I execute without compiling first:

```
c:\standalone-jpa>mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=tomczak.jpa.JpaTest
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building standalone-jpa 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:java (default-cli) @ standalone-jpa ---
[WARNING] Warning: killAfter is now deprecated. Do you need it ? Please comment
on MEXEC-6.
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tomczak.jpa.JpaTest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.731s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 02 09:18:59 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/146M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then, you should run your command again:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="your.Class"
```

Answer (score -1):

For my case, I had the **wrong [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)** version installed. I needed the 7.6 for my dependencies but I had the 3.6.

I removed and installed `npm` to the newest version:

```
sudo apt-get remove npm && sudo apt-get autoremove
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc
nvm install 7.6
nvm use 7
```